# MySQL binary log after restore

Tags: mysql, windows, database-backups

I've got an issue with a legacy system I've inherited. Every night a dump from live is run (to script) and restored to QA from said script e.g.:

```
mysql [params] < path/to/backup.sql
```

This causes the creation of lots data in the bin logs (DB is a few gigabytes). The bin logs don't seem to get flushed automatically - I can clear them down by running `RESET MASTER;` from the mysql command line but was wondering if there was any way to automate this? It's running on mysql 4.0.21 under Windows.

EDIT: 
It's not running as a master to any slave dbs

Comment: great, just comment out log-bin in the mysql configuration and restart the mysqld should disabled the bin logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flush logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html)
or update & restart mysql server by comment out `log-bin = xxx`,
but this will disabled the replication

Answer (score 0):

The following will disable sql statements being logged to binary.

```
mysql> set sql_log_bin=0
mysql> source path/to/backup.sql
```

This applies to current thread only and is much faster.